# Python - split on tab and create a new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. I have raw data that is split into '\t' and \n'

Sample data:

```
Apple   Fruit
Orange  Fruit
Car Vehicle
Truck   Vehicle
```

Output should look like with '\n' in between:

```
Apple
Fruit

Orange
Fruit

Car
Vehicle

Truck
Vehicle
```

Here is what I tried:

```
filename = open('data/att.txt','r')
rdata = filename.read()
print(rdata)

{line.strip().split('\t')[0]:line.split('\t')[1] for line in rdata.splitlines() if line.strip() = '\n'}
```

I keep getting invalid syntax error. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Since you're new to Python, try writing up a loop. Your issue is that in your dict comprehension, it should be `line.strip() == '\n'`, but there are many cleaner ways of doing this that are more efficient and readable

Comment: To test for equality, use double equal: `if line.strip() == '\n'`

Comment: Do you want this output on a screen or save it to use later?

Comment: Simply replacing `'\t`' with `'\n'` and printing another newline after the whole line seems much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
{line.strip().split('\t')[0]:line.split('\t')[1] for line in rdata.splitlines() if line.strip() == '\n'}
```

Use "==" to test for equality and "=" to set value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code might help you to avoid the error that was the "=" instead of "==" and also help you to convert it into a more readable code.

```
file = open('data/att.txt','r')
for line in file :
   aux = line.strip().split('\t')
   print(aux[0])
   print(aux[1], end='\n\n')
```